# React synthetic event: onDrag doesn't fire after onClick or onContextMenu is called

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am developing a React application which uses canvas drawings. I am trying to detect Drag like this:

```
<canvas className="mycanvas" onDrag ={this.moveObj} onDragStart={this.startMoving} onDragEnd={this.stopMoving} onDoubleClick={this.createSelectedObj}  ref={(mycanvas)=>{this.mycanvas= mycanvas;} }></canvas>
```

I am able to drag the object till I either click or right click on the canvas. After Click or right Click, if I try drag it doesn't fire. It fires only after I double click on the canvas.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was because in HTML5 onDrag and other drag related events are designed for drag and drop of elements. It fires only in drag & drop context.

To implement dragging behavior in canvas I used classic

> mousedown, mouseup and mousemove events

and used

```
onDragStart={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();}
```

to prevent drag start under drag and drop context.